# Existence of convergent sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Let $(A_n)$ be a set sequence in a Banach space such that $A_n$ is nonempty, closed and convex for every $n=1,2,\dots$. Assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{n,m\to \infty} d(A_n,A_m)=0$ where $d$ is Hausdorff distance between two sets. My question is whether there exists a convergent sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying $x_n\in A_n$ for every $n$?

Comment: Now asked on MathOverflow: [About the existence of a convergent sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/q/273611).